# how to add existing core to the solr search in local

Tags: solr, full-text-search, solrcloud, solr4, solr-search

How to add core in the local machine which is configured on the server?
I moved my core under "solr" directory but is not visible in solr panel (localhost:8983).

When I try to create a new one with the same name I got an error that core already exists. After that my core name is displayed in solr panel but can't able to import data using "/dataimport". it shows below response but not fetching any record.

```
{
"responseHeader": {
                  "status": 0,
                  "QTime": 3
                  },
"initArgs": ["defaults",["config","db-data-config.xml"]],
"command": "status",  
"status": "busy",
"importResponse": "A command is still running...",
"statusMessages": {
"Time Elapsed": "0:0:0.5",
"Total Requests made to DataSource": "0",
"Total Rows Fetched": "0",
"Total Documents Processed": "0",
"Total Documents Skipped": "0",
"Full Dump Started": "2020-02-19 06:13:20" 
}}
```

But No record displayed in the "Execute query". Is there any doc to add an existing core to another solr search?

Comment: check if this could be if any help https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/making-and-restoring-backups.html

Answer (score 0):

do you have it in your solr.xml? only the cores listed in solr.xml will be visible in the cores list.

or you can do a add core through the GUI